# Is it possible to animate domain in mantaflow simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to animate the movement of a cube (domain) with water like here: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbJCErTo7Vk), but the water sticks to the bottom of cube (domain).

[image]
[image]

If i try to use an effector as a cube the water just goes through it...

Is it possible to do this?